# htaccess css / js / images redirect based on subdomain string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the images, css, js and some other folders based on the subdomain string:

www:

- **www**.domain.com/css/main.css --> /**site**/css/main.css
- **www**.domain.com/images/logo.png --> /**site**/images/logo.png

all other subdomains:

- **other1**.domain.com/css/main.css --> /**app**/css/main.css
- **other2**.domain.com/css/main.css --> /**app**/css/main.css
- **otherX**.domain.com/js/script.js --> /**app**/js/script.js

All the other requests have to be routed through index.php

What I have so far is partly working:

```
#THIS BLOCK WORKS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] # <--DON'T KNOW ABOUT THESE FLAGS

# SUBDOMAIN - THIS PART WORKS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.subdomain\.[a-z] <--# ADDED [a-z] .dev or .com
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /app/css/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /app/js/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /app/assets/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /app/images/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /app/uploads/$1 [R,NC,L]

# OR

# WWW - THIS PART WORKS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.[a-z] <--# ADDED [a-z] .dev or .com
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /site/css/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /site/js/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /site/assets/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /site/images/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /site/uploads/$1 [R,NC,L]

# BUT NOT TOGETHER

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I can't get the two sets of rules both work together.

Preferably I'd like to have something like:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.[a-z]

RewriteRule ^(.*?).(php|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf)/(.*)$ /app/css/$1 [L]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With just one sleepless night I found it!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.[a-z]
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|assets)/(.*)$ /app/$1/$2 [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.[a-z]
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|assets)/(.*)$ /site/$1/$2 [R,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```